# ListView under constraint layout disappears in preview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

[image]

**Output png**

So below is my xml for the activity:
I have migrated to androidx from support libraries.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/partyname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:hint="@string/firm_name"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/billform"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttons"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/partyname">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/identifier"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:hint="@string/code_article"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/add" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttons"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/billform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For god knows why, the listView is not available in the preview.
It works when the root is linear layout. I tried creating a linear layout within the constraint layout, it didn't work

**EDIT: 1**
The comment by **Harshad** did it for me

Comment: if you're using constraint then remove all the nested layouts. the point of constraint layout is flat layout.

Comment: Ok, what are flat layouts and what to use for flat layouts? Also, the answer that you provided and my code, will the ui behavior stay the same?

Answer (score 2):

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

That might be your problem or if you are talking about not seeing items then it might be a bug in android studio because I tried adding another ConstraintLayout without getting any luck.

[This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744221/using-listview-inside-constraintlayout)

I wanted to add my answer as a comment but StackOverflow won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

change the width from match_parent to 0dp and you can create left and right constraint.The following will work for you.

```
<ListView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/billform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

**Update**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/partyname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:hint="@string/firm_name"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/identifier"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:hint="@string/code_article"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/add"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/add"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/partyname"/>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttons"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/partyname"/>

       <ListView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            tools:listitem="Add items here"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So I dont need to remove the nested layouts? and using layout_width="0dp", wont it throw any warnings?

Comment: The aim of the Constraint Layout is to help reduce the number of nested views.You don't need to use linear layout inside constraint layout.Constraint  allows us to lay out child views using ‘constraints’ to define position based relationships between different views found in our layout.

Comment: tried this code, didn't work. I should make this clear, the problem I am facing is that list view is not previewed in the design mode. I am adding the screenshot of the output, for further clarification.

Comment: @HarshPatalia seem like you have't added `tools:listitem="@layout/row_list"` if you want to preview your list just add this to your `ListView` in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the nested layouts.
Try the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/partyname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/identifier"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/add"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/partyname" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/identifier" />

<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add" />
```